Proving that two points are isogonal and then proving Pascal's Theorem
The Wikipedia entry for Pascal's Theorem includes the following proof:

The diagram is as follows

where the two indicated triangles are colored brown and blue and my interpretation of "we overlap the similar triangles" is in magenta. I simply can't see what this has to do with isogonal conjugates and Pascal's Theorem. The terminology is also a problem because the usual expression is $P$ and $Q$ are isogonal conjugates in $\triangle ABC$, not that they "will correspond to the isogonal conjugates".

See Theorem 4 on the Even Chen blog here

I have studied this document, too, but there is some cognitive block preventing me from understanding these presentations of the proof. I would appreciate some detail of how to approach it.

As Jean Marie also mentioned in the comments, the story is done in a wonderful manner on Evan Chen's blog. This answer brings nothing new compared with this source, but uses the configuration of points in the cyclic order on the circle as in the posted image, and digests things also in a separate picture.
So we start with the following situation:

Now imagine a "homothety" move of the green triangle $\Delta YCF$, so that it is mapped onto the gray triangle $\Delta YCE$.
(Explicitly, to visualize the process, do the following. Reflect $C,F$ w.r.t. the point $Y$ to obtain two points $C^r$, $F^r$. Now $C^rF^r$ is "antiparallel" to $EB$ in the gray triangle. To have parallelism, reflect $C^r$, $F^r$ w.r.t. the angle bisector in $Y$, obtaining two points $C^*,F^*$. Now $C^*$ is on $YE$, an $F^*$ on $YB$. Then use a dilation centered in $Y$ to bring $C^*,F^*$ in the same time into $E,B$.
Also move the two marked angles that are related to the green triangle in the world of the gray triangle. Since $YC$, respectively $YF$ is mapped to $YE$, respectively $YB$ the situation is as follows:

Some points are kept. The point $Z'$ is new, and it corresponds to the point $Z$, the green segments $Z'E$, $Z'B$ thus correspond to $ZC$, $ZF$.
Let $I$ be the incenter of the gray $\Delta YEB$.
Observe now that in this configuration:

The lines $XE$, $ZE$ (cevians from $E$) are reflected in each other w.r.t. $EI$, the angle bisector in $E$ in the gray triangle.
The lines $XB$, $ZB$ (cevians from $B$) are reflected in each other w.r.t. $BI$, the angle bisector in $B$ in the gray triangle.

Two cevians determine the intersection point.
So the cevians from the third vertex, $Y$ for the points $X$ and $Z$ are also reflected in each other w.r.t. the angle bisector $YI$.

Undo now the "homothety move". Only the reflection affects it $YZ'$, and it becomes $YZ$ when undone. since $YX$ and $YZ'$ were isogonal, we obtain $YX=YZ$. Thus the wanted colinearity.
$\square$

Nice! Though I had to look up "homothety" ....

Other common words that are closer to the intuition are contraction/dilation and rescaling (using a constant factor, from a fixed center).
